# Java Jackson deserialize abstract class child which implements interface

Tags: java, jackson

I have an interface:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
        use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
        property = "type")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildA.class, name = "childA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildB.class, name = "childB"),
})
public interface Event {
}
```

And then abstract class which implements this interface:

```
public abstract class SpecificEvent implements Event {
    private ZonedDateTime timestamp;
}
```

And finally children of abstract class:

```
public class ChildA extends SpecificEvent {
}

public class ChildB extends SpecificEvent {
}
```

Jackson fails to deserialize children with error:

> Could not resolve type id 'childA' as a subtype of
> `packages.SpecificEvent`.

What am i doing wrong?

**UPD**

I'm consuming messages of children throw RabbitMQ.
Rabbit config:

```
   public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        var mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.registerModule(new Jdk8Module());
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, true);
        mapper.setDateFormat(StdDateFormat.instance
                .withTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow")))
                .withLocale(new Locale("ru"))
        );
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        return mapper;
    }

    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper());
    }
```

For sending events i just use RabbitTemplate:

```
    rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(
            exchange.getName(),
            event.getEventRouteKey().getKey(),
            event
    );
```

And listen to it via @RabbitListener.

Comment: How is Jackson called? In a controller? Can you show the code?

Comment: @Mafor, hello, thank you for the reply, i've updated question description.

Comment: Can you provide an example JSON which fails to be deserialized?

Comment: @AlexRudenko, hello, thank you for the reply,but i've already figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, i forgot to purge queue in Rabbit, before changing the models, that's why i got deserialization error.